# Degree of Freedom in DoE modeling

Tags: regression, anova, experiment-design

Past the standard full factorial and fractional designs, I am getting the impression that non-regular designs (OME, Hall, mixed-level OA, etc.) are just trying to fit in as many factors as possible. This implicates the later regression analysis.

Assume $X_{n*m} $design matrix, the overall degree of freedom would be $n-1$. Why is it a good idea to use up all d.f. on factors (hence $m=n-1$, assume standard encoding) and leaving 0 d.f. for residual?